# Socket descriptor files remain on disk after program exits

Tags: python, zeromq

I'm using zeromq to send numpy arrays between processes in Python.
After the program exits, a file named `zmq_endpoint` remains on disk.
I've tried to explicitly close the socket and the context, but that didn't help.

What should I do to properly cleanup on exit?

PUSH side:

```
        endpoint = "zmq_endpoint"

        # Start process for PULL socket
        self._io_proc = Process(target=_video_processing_func, args=(endpoint,))
        self._io_proc.start()

        # Create PUSH socket
        self._zmq_context = zmq.Context()
        self._socket = self._zmq_context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
        self._socket.connect(f"ipc://{endpoint}")

        ...

        # Send a message over the socket
        self._socket.send(b'data', flags=zmq.NOBLOCK | zmq.SNDMORE)
        self._socket.send(str(len(msg.frames)).encode('ascii'), flags=zmq.NOBLOCK | zmq.SNDMORE)

        for frame in frames:
            send_array(self._socket, frame, flags=zmq.NOBLOCK | zmq.SNDMORE)

        self._socket.send(b'end', flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)

        ...

        # Cleanup
        self._socket.send(b'stop', flags=zmq.NOBLOCK)
        self._io_proc.join(5)

        self._socket.close(linger=1)
        self._zmq_context.term()
```

PULL side:

```
def _video_recording_func(endpoint):
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
    socket.bind(f"ipc://{endpoint}")

    try:
        while True:
            msg = socket.recv()
            if msg == b'data':
                # Receive data from queue
                n_frames = int(socket.recv())

                for i in range(n_frames):
                    frm = recv_array(socket)
                    # Process frame...

                assert socket.recv() == b'end'

            elif msg == b'stop':
                break
            else:
                assert False, "Corrupt message received in queue"
    finally:
        for writer in video_writers:
            if writer is not None:
                writer.release()
        socket.close(linger=1)
        context.term()
```

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8.10
- pyzmq 22.3.0
- libzmq 4.3.4

Comment: In general, what you're showing here looks like desirable behavior. If you make a server delete a handle when it shuts down, that introduces potential race conditions (depending on the details of the object's behavior and the platform at hand) by meaning that the same directory can point to two different objects depending on when it was opened.

Comment: That gets especially nasty on platforms where files can be deleted while there's still an open handle on them, because then you can have two processes running at the same time thinking they both have `ipc://zmq_endpoint` open, but actually having _two different_ objects open under the same name.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you're really sure you want to unlink the file, have you tried using `os.unlink()` (or its synonym `os.remove()`)?

Comment: I don't feel comfortable deleting the file explicitly, as I wasn't the one to create it... This would be assuming a certain implementation of zmq sockets, which I'd expect to be abstracted from me.

Comment: Also, unfortunately there's more than one such descriptor. Each run generates at least one new file with a different name.

Comment: So zmq has no built-in way of cleaning up file artifacts from disk after the program exits?

Comment: Is it really a file, or a named socket? If it's really a file (has blocks, takes up filesystem space) there might be a reason to worry about it. If it's just a named socket, put it in a tmpfs location (f/e `/run/yourservice` -- systemd can create and manage such directories automatically if you tell it to) and leave it be. Using `/run` means it's cleaned up on reboot, but persistent within an OS session, so you don't get the race conditions I referenced above.

Comment: ..._oh_, you're on Windows. Ignore what I said about systemd and `/run`; different platform, I don't know the conventions there.